# Making this code with Map and Set more Scala-ish

Tags: scala

How do I make these line of codes more scala-ish (shorter?). I still get the Java feeling in it (which I want to stay away from). Thanks in advance!

```
import scala.collection.mutable
val outstandingUserIds: mutable.LinkedHashSet[String] = mutable.LinkedHashSet[String]()    

val tweetJson = JacksMapper.readValue[Map[String, AnyRef]](body)     
val userObj = tweetJson.get("user")    
tweetJson.get("user").foreach(userObj => {
  userObj.asInstanceOf[Map[String, AnyRef]].get("id_str").foreach(idStrObj => {
    if (outstandingUserIds.exists(outstandingIdStr => outstandingIdStr.equals(idStrObj))) {
      outstandingUserIds.remove(idStrObj.asInstanceOf[String])
    }
  })
})
```

Comment: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Thanks. Will move it there.

Comment: Now that you have moved it, you should delete this question from here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One thing you want to do in Scala is take advantage of type inference. That way, you don't need to repeat yourself on the LHS:

```
val outstandingUserIds = mutable.LinkedHashSet[String]()
```

You also don't need the inner braces after the closure variable `userObj =>`. Instead, use braces after foreach {} to execute multiple statements:

```
tweetJson.get("user").foreach { userObj =>

}
```

In fact, you could use the anonymous variable '_' and say:

```
tweetJson.get("user").foreach {
   _.get("id_str").foreach ...
}
```

Scala encourages the use of immutable collections. One way to simplify the above even further would be to use `collect` (instead of `exists`+`delete`) which would return a new collection with only the elements you want.